# How to store server password in Java client for later reconnects?

Tags: java, debugging, passwords, keystore

I have a client application that connects to a server over a secure/SSL socket.  The user is required to log in when the app starts.  Right now I have a requirement that I need to send the actual password to the server (encrypted over the SSL), instead of the preferred method of sending a hash of the password.  With that said, how do I go about securely storing the password in the client memory such that I can re-use this password if the client needs to reconnect to the server behind the scenes due to a lost connection?

I can easily encrypt the password, or even put it into a KeyStore and retrieve it later for the reconnect, however, even if I do this, it seems to me a hacker could retrieve the password if he had access to the application in a debugger.  Is this just a fact of life when one needs to store the password on the client for a temporary time?

Is there a better/preferred way of achieving the same thing (i.e. allowing the client to reconnect to the server without requiring the user to enter his password again after the initial login)?  Would an expiring login token sent from the server be a better way to go (where I can pass this expiring token back to the server instead of a password upon a reconnect)?

Finally, in general, how easy is it for someone to connect a debugger to a running application on Java desktop or Android, when the Application is correctly 'stripped' of debugging symbols?  Do I even need to worry about this case, or will Java protect my shipping application from having a debugger, or other memory analyzer, attach to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do nothing against a (system-wide) key logger in your application. So storing the password in memory is risky but less risky than session tokens:

A hacker can use a malicious client that has faked a SSL/secure reconnection and brute-forces the tokens. This approach would impose more risks than storing the password in memory.

Comment: I don't understand why a token would be any more vulnerable to a brute-force attack than the hacker trying to brute force attack the password?

Comment: Because, generally, tokens are more structured than passwords. Also; the tokens are send as-is (as it should map to the session on the server side), while passwords can be hashed (same passwords map to same "unknown" data; less predictable). Another risk is in the development effort; one must create a session and token authentication layer, while using the relatively "simple" password technique requires less effort. Let's say a programmer introduces a bug every 5 minutes. Less time to implement then means less bugs.

Answer (score 1):

> a hacker could retrieve the password if he had access to the application in a debugger.

Correct.  The hacker also has access to the password when they watch the user type by looking over the user's physical shoulder with their physical eyeballs.

And the hacker has access after they store a keylogger on the users computer.

> Is this just a fact of life when one needs to store the password on the client for a temporary time?

No.

The alternative is for you to personally visit each user and tell them not to use the debugger to break security.

Let's just think about the use case where the user (who knows the password) fires up the application in a debugger to learn the password.  Which they already knew.

After thinking about the only use case in which the user fires up the client application running under a debugger, I'm not sure security is "broken", since they already knew the password.

I guess it would be possible for Henry Hacker to start the app in the debugger, conceal that on another display by turning the power off, then running to get the real user and having them type in their password on a development workstation that has one of the monitors turned off.  Is that the "access to the application in a debugger" scenario you're talking about?

> Do I even need to worry about this case,

Not really

> or will Java protect my shipping application from having a debugger, or other memory analyzer, attach to it?

No, Java doesn't protect your users.  Common sense protects your users.

If a debugger is running, they shouldn't be using the computer.

And 99% of the time, they won't get a debugger started.

1% of the time, they'll accidentally run a debugger -- because users click random icons.  Of those 1% will actually get your application to run under the debugger.  Again, by clicking random icons.  Of those 1% will actually get to the place where they could type in a password by clicking random icons on the screen.

It **could** happen that a user could somehow run your client under a debugger.  But.  Since they already know the password, there's little point in worrying about it.

---

This is entirely different from a man-in-the-middle attack or a remote control attack.

If someone takes remote control of your user's computer, runs the debugger, and watches the transaction, that's entirely separate.  That's stopped by firewalls and operating systems.  Not Java.

---

> put it into a KeyStore and retrieve it later for the reconnect

That's all you can ever do.  The "connect a debugger" scenario cannot be prevented by your applications.  It's the OS's job to alert the user that a debugger is being connected.

If you're worried about liability, don't store passwords.  End of liability.

Comment: A debugger can also be used as an API used by a virus without a GUI.

Comment: @S.Lott, I disagree, I think it should be a concern (though there isn't much that can be done about it). You could walk away from your PC, I walk up with a debugger or memory analyzer

Comment: Can't the hacker just attach a debugger or a memory analyzer to an already running application if the user leaves his desk, or in the mobile case, someone steals the user's phone while the app is logged in?

Comment: @Android Dev: First, the hacker has to get the user to leave their desk unlocked.  If the hacker can do that, they can look over the user's shoulder, or -- better -- buy the user a few drinks and get the password that way.  There's a limit to "technical means" and at some point, you have to recognize that social engineering exists and will trump all of the possible technology-centric scenarios.  There's a limit.

Comment: @SLott: If I leave my Android phone at a restaurant with app running, and screen unlocked, DDMS can be used by person who found phone to dump all memory and view strings.  That is what I need to worry about in this financial app I am writing.

Comment: @Android Dev: "That is what I need to worry about".  If you worry about that, you also need to worry about drunk users disclosing passwords (since that's **more** likely).  You also need to worry about hackers stealing the phone.  And -- since you started out worrying about debuggers -- you need to worry about compromised phones in which malware has been pre-installed by the vendor who sold it used on eBay.  And, don't forget to worry about bad guys robbing the phone at gun point (or knife-point) mid-transaction.  I'm sure there are an infinite number of scenarios you can worry about.

Comment: @SLott -- I appreciate your laundry list of scenarios where passwords can be acquired.  However, as you already know, I can't guard against all these.  But I am trying to guard against the ones I know I can guard against (which reduces my legal liability).  It is very easy to dump the memory of an Android app -- I just tried it on one of the Android apps I installed from the Marketplace.

Comment: @Android Dev: Since it's so easy, then you can't store it, can you?  Why ask?  "But I am trying to guard against the ones I know I can guard against".  Actually, that's not true.  Your question asks to guard against a scenario ("connect a debugger") that you cannot guard against.  That scenario is just as impossible to guard against as all other attacks that involve social engineering or OS vulnerabilities.  If you're worried about users (who know the password) using a debugger to find the password (they already know) then don't store passwords.

Comment: @SLott -- I don't care about the user who knows the password connecting a debugger.  I care about someone else, other than the user, who would steal, find, or otherwise acquire a phone that is not theirs, and connect either a debugger, or a memory analyzer/dumper, to the phone while the app is still logged in with the "real" user's main account.  I am sorry if you can't seem to comprehend this scenario, but the scenario exists, and it happens a lot more than you think, especially in the industry I am in.

Comment: @Android Dev: I can't comprehend the scenario.  I'm sorry, but it is identical to armed robbery.  I don't see how technical means prevent that.  I really don't.    Here's the bottom line.  Again.  Since it's so easy to crack the password, then you can't store it, can you?.  Why Ask?

Answer (score 0):

I would do what you suggest, create some kind of session token on the server side. Associate it with the user, and send it back to the client.

Depends on what you mean by easy. I think it's rather easy to debug Java applications even if they are stripped of debugging symbols. Might even be able to debug them if they are obfuscated.